# Godot: application is not fullscreen

Tags: android, godot

When I run my game, the test window display correctly my game, but not when I run on my android phone. The game is resize and a grey rectangle appears at the bottom of the screen.

[Screen of the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK8g7.jpg)

[The project's parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtwgg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that:

- The Stretch Aspect is set to Expand on the project settings -> general -> display -> window (this setting is not visible on the picture, you need to scroll down). See [Multiple resolutions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/rendering/multiple_resolutions.html).
- And you are either:

  - Not using `Control`s for the UI.
  - Or you didn't set the layout to Full. See [Size and anchors](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/size_and_anchors.html).
- The default clear color is Gray (which is the default) on project settings -> general -> rendering -> environment. *You can change the color to match your background. Or if you are mainly using solid color backgrounds, you can use that instead of a `ColorRect` or whatever you are using.*

Test your game on desktop, windowed (not full-screen) and resizable (and not borderless). That way you can and resize the window to different sizes to see how it behaves. *I remind you that different smartphones have different screen sizes.*

*Unrelated: you need allow hidpi to have the game window show up at all in some monitors.*

Comment: OK, I change the strech aspect to ignore, and now the game fill the screen. Thank you !